# $\iint_D \sin(\frac{y-x}{y+x})dydx$ over a trapezoid $D$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

An exercise in my Analysis book:

Find $\iint_D \sin(\frac{y-x}{y+x})dydx$ on a trapezoid $D$ with vertices $(0,1), (0,2), (2,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

How do I approach this problem? I tried to find a one-to-one function to transform the trapezoid into a square or something easier, but failed at that.

Perhaps one could integrate over the triangle $(0,2), (2,0), (0,0)$ and then integrate over the triangle $(0,1), (1,0), (0,0)$. Then subtract the two integrals to get the desired result. However, I am also having trouble solving these integrals.

Any help?

Comment: The form of the integral screams change of variables.

Comment: how about  $u = x+y, v = x-y$

Comment: @Paul very likely, yes.. The section is on that subject. May I ask what so clearly indicates that this is the case here?

Comment: It's just very hard to integrate sine of a fraction like this without some lucky coincidences.

Comment: @DougM I think I can work out the integrand for that integral. However I am puzzled as to how do describe area $D$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Should I use the equalities $x = (u-v)/2$ and $y = (u+v)/2$? I suppose I need them to calculate the Jacobian, at least. (I used $u= y+x$ and $v=y-x$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u = x + y\\
v = x - y\\
du\,dv = 2 \ dx\, dy$

Your region maps to $(1,-1), (2,-2)(2,2), (1,1)$
Still a trapezoid, but oriented it a way that easier to work with.

$\int_1^2 \int_{-u}^{u}  \frac 12 \sin \frac {v}{u}\ dv\ du$

Comment: How do you find out where the region maps to? EDIT: Apparently fill in (four times) the x-y coordinates into the $u$ and $v$ definitions. However, how can I be sure that the whole initial trapezoid is mapped onto the new tetrahedron with these vertices? So $T(x,y):D^*\to D$ defined as $T(x,y)=(x+y,x-y)$.

Comment: you have 4$ (x,y)$ coordinates for points.  You map them to the appropriate points in $(u,v)$ space.  A linear transformation if you want to sound fancy.  Plug the respective $x,y$ values into the definitions of $u,v$ if you don't.  When you have the transformed vertexes, What are equations of the lines that border the region?

Comment: $v=u, v=-u, u=1, u=2$. However I wonder how one can be sure that the linear transformation is one-to-one?

Comment: Sorry, trapeziod, not tetrahedron.  How do you know that the transform is 1-1.  You could say, the transformation matrix is full rank.  The transform amounts to a rotation of the plane with a dilation factor.

Comment: @QuestionMaker As long as the transformation isn’t singular, it’ll be one-to-one. One of the nice properties of linear transformations. Based on the transformation’s Jacobian, what can you conclude?

Comment: @amd I am trying to evaluate the integral stated above and if I made no mistakes I'm getting 0 as an answer.. I know little about Jacobians except for how to calculate them. It's equal to $1/2$ here.

Comment: @QuestionMaker A somewhat different tack, then. Can you find the matrix of the coordinate transformation? If its determinant is non-zero, then the transformation is non-singular.

Comment: I get that the integral equals $0,$ too.  $\sin x$ is an odd function, and it is being evaluated over a region that is symmetric.  As far as what is the jacobian (intuitively), it is a measure of how your transformation distorts area.  A square that is $1\times 1$ in $x,y$ space is $\sqrt 2 \times \sqrt 2$ in $u,v$ space... or $\ du\ dv = 2\ dx\ dy$ or $\ dx\ dy = \frac 12 \ du\ dv$

Comment: @amd I guess the matrix would be $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: That’s right. And its determinant is...?